# -keyhook parameter is not working with VcXsrv on Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vcxsrv

I am running Xfce in Full-Screen mode using Windows Subsystem for Linux and VcXsrv. I'd like to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to alternate between open Xfce programs. However when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> it triggers Windows's applications switch. I have already tried the argument `-keyhook` with no success. I can archive a similar behavior with Virtual Box when I have to use <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to escape the Virtual Machine's window.

Answer (score 2):

Using X2Go, I had to adjust the default server settings a bit to get it working. [(source: programmersought.com)](http://www.programmersought.com/article/4076213653/;jsessionid=F0CEF12F068DAA2943B4E1B705333025)

Currently I am running the server as:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe" -clipboard -nopn :0 -keyhook -rootless
```

For me (Windows 10, v1903) the solution was to use `-keyhook` combined with `-rootless`. In `-multiwindow` mode, the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key was captured, but not <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Specifically for X2Go, the settings look like this for me:

[image]

```
.-- Settings -------------------------------------------------------------------.
|   .---------.----------.-----------------------.--------------------.         |
|   | General | Printing | X.Org Server Settings | PulseAudio Settings|         |
| .----------------------'                       '----------------------------. |
| | You must restart the X2Go Client for the changes to take effect           | |
| |                                                                           | |
| |                                                                           | |
| |                                                                           | |
| |                                                                           | |
| | ( ) use integrated X-Server                                               | |
| | [ ] do not use primary clipboard                                          | |
| | (x) use custom X-Server                                                   | |
| |                                                                           | |
| | .-- custom X-server ----------------------------------------------------. | |
| | |             .------------------------------------------------------.  | | |
| | | executable: | C:/Program Files (x86)/x2goclient/VcXsrv/vcxsrv.exe  |  | | |
| | |             '------------------------------------------------------'  | | |
| | | [x] start X-server on X2Go Client start                               | | |
| | |                       .--------------------------------------------.  | | |
| | | command line options: | -clipboard -nopn :0 -keyhook -rootless     |  | | |
| | |                       '--------------------------------------------'  | | |
| | '-----------------------------------------------------------------------' | |
| |                                            .----. .--------. .----------. | |
| |                                            | OK | | Cancel | | Defaults | | |
| |                                            '----' '--------' '----------' | |
| '---------------------------------------------------------------------------' |
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```